# What is the difference between (click) and (change) in Angular5?

Tags: angular5

I am new to angular5 and having trouble understanding the difference between (click) and (change):

```
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"
                   (click)="onSourceDatabaseChange($event, row,i)"
                   (change)="onSourceDatabaseChange($event, row, i)"                       
 </mat-row>
```

When do they fire and what do they do?

Comment: Those are two different events.

Comment: One is fired when the element is clicked on, one is fired when the element changes, like with different content typed into an `<input>` field.

Comment: Okay so if you click the row (mat-row) the (click) event fires and optionally if the row's "row"(let row) model changes then (change) is fired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(click)` calls the specified function when a user clicks on the given element (in your example, when a user clicks on a row.

The `(change)` event binds to HTML's onChange event. This event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.

The `(change)` event can also be specifically implemented by other Angular components. It is generally implemented on components where the contents of the component are changed by the user.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. Do you have a reference to the (change) event doesn't always exist on an element? I am trying to figure out what events I have available for different elements.

Comment: You will need to look at documentation for each element you want to know about. For pure html elements look at HTML documentation to see if the onChange event is available. When using Angular components from other libraries, look at the documentation for those libraries.